# Passing a Set to a Child Component in Angular

Tags: angular, set, angular-directive

I have the a list of checkboxes which are identified by `id: number`([Gist for the Data as JSON](https://gist.github.com/shantanoo-desai/5163182aba74baf7ec04d7ac426bd944)). If I check the first checkbox then the `id` value is stored into the `Set`.

My **ParentComponent** is as following:

`parent.component.ts` code snippet

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as FilterFunc from 'src/assets/FilterFunction.json';

const Filters: any = FilterFunc;

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  filters = Filters.default;
  selections = new Set();

  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  changeCheck(id: number, event: any) {
    (event.target.checked) ?
      this.selections.add(id):
      this.selections.delete(id);

  }
}
```

`parent.component.html` code Snippet:

```
<!--- ....>
<div *ngFor="let label of filter['labels']">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input"
                   type="checkbox"
                   value="{{label['id']}}"
                   id="{{label['id']}}"
                   [(ngModel)]="label['checked']"
                   (change)="changeCheck(label['id'], $event)"
            >
              <label class="form-check-label" for="{{label['id']}}">
                {{label['name']}}
              </label>
          </div>
      </div>
```

I wish to pass this `selections: Set` to a child component and within the Parent's HTML component I added the following:

```
<child [selected]=selections></child>
```

within the **ChildComponent**:

`child.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
  providers: [
    // service that I need
  ]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {


  @Input()selected: any; // not sure if `Set` is a type for a variable in TS

  constructor(private service: ExploreService) { }

  ngOnInit() {      }

   someFunct() {
      // Use the incoming `selected` here.
   }

}
```

`child.component.html`

```
   {{ selected | json }}
```

But it provides me only `{}` in the Browser whenever I check a checkbox and according to `changeCheck` the `selections` should have added the values in the `Set`

If I use `{{selected}}` it keeps providing me `[object Set]`. How do I pass the `Set` from Parent to Child Component?

Upon using `OnChange` Directive in the child component I do the following:

```
ngOnChanges(change: SimpleChange) {
console.log(change.currentValue);
}
```

This provides me the Set() but the `selected` is still an empty set in the Browser's console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible way to send to the child was to convert the `Set` to an array and then to pass it along the Child Component

I had to create a private member as a `Set`, and had to convert it to the `Array`

```
private _selections = new Set();
selections: number[] = [];
```

within the `changeCheck(id: number, event: any)` function at the end of checking the event

```
(event.target.checked) ? this._selection.add(id) : this._selection.delete(id);
this.selections = Array.from(this._selections);
```

Finally it will work with `OnChanges` hook when everytime the parent passes the ID value.